# MobaXterm SFTP and FTP Stopped Working

Tags: mobaxterm

SFTP and FTP on MobaXterm Personal Edition have stopped working for me for some reason. I get a blank yellow and blank green windows when I try to open a SFTP or FTP session, respectively. MobaXterm SSH works fine to same servers. SFTP to same servers works fine from Windows 10 command line. I am using Windows 10 Pro Version 1903 and have tried MobaXterm version 11 and version 20.1 Build 4290, Personal Edition. MobaXterm SFTP was working before on same windows machine. I am trying to SFTP to Raspberry Pi and a VM in the cloud. This was working before. I use MobaXterm at work on a Windows 10 Pro machine SFTPing and SSHing to RHEL machines; however, I am using MobaXterm Professional there. That is working. I don't think the Pro version should make a difference. Also, I get a strange Application Error/Exception EAccessViolation in module MobaXterm.exe at XXXXXXX window when I shut MobaXterm down. This only happens after I have tried to open a SFTP session during a MobaXterm session and then close.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a leap year bug. Set your date to 3/1/2020 on your OS and you will be able to use MobaXterm. Otherwise, wait until tomorrow or hope MobaXterm fixes this themselves.

Source is another progam that had a similar error:
https://forums.boxifier.com/t/fixed-application-error/519/8

They claimed it was a leap year bug. Tested by setting my OS date to 3/1/2020, and now MobaXterm SFTP/FTP works. Hope this helps!